# Send email from windows application (C++)

Tags: email, windows

I am programming a process monitoring tool which is written in C++, windows application. Is there anyway to send out alert email when the tool find the process go down? Any library support this? or any solution is fine. Thanks.

Comment: Mail through MS-Outlook might not be an option since this tool has to be deployed on many machines. Will take a look at POCO. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) has SMTP support

There is also a way to do mail through MS-Outlook http://www.outlookcode.com/

Answer (score 1):

In order to send mail on a Windows box you can use the MAPI interface:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296721(VS.85).aspx

This will use the settings for Outlook/Outlook Express (possibly others) to send it. It may require the user to actually give permission for the e-mail to be sent. (It probably depends on user settings) It will also only work if e-mail is configured correctly on the box.

I have in the past had the program send a web request with the details and used that to send an e-mail. However, that was when my program had crashed and I needed the bug report. I do not think that is what you had in mind.

You could also implement the SMTP connection yourself.

However, that will require knowing the SMTP settings for the user which may be inconvenient.